# Creating a toggleable menu using only javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, menu, bookmarklet

I am attempting to create a menu using only vanilla javascript. No css or html. This menu must also be able to have buttons, that run more javascript. (this is for a bookmarklet)

I tried looking around the internet for similar tihngs, but none have been able to work in a bookmarklet.

Comment: Good luck with this. Come back when you have specific questions about your code, we can't help you with doing this from scratch.

Comment: Doing this without HTML or CSS is crazy. That's why you can't find similar things in your search.

Comment: You should check how the browser renders a web page. You can not create web page only with javascript.

https://medium.com/jspoint/how-the-browser-renders-a-web-page-dom-cssom-and-rendering-df10531c9969

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with "without HTML and CSS", if you just mean that you want to create all the HTML and CSS dynamically with JavaScript it is possible.

In the example below we create a menu element using JavaScript and fill it with html for the options, we then create a style element and add css rules to it and finally we add an event listener so that we can react on menu choices.

```js
const menuOptions = [
  'Eat',
  'Sleep',
  'Play'
];

// create the menu
const menu = document.createElement('menu');
menu.classList.add('dynMenu');
menu.innerHTML = menuOptions.map(x => `<div>${x}</div>`).join('');
document.body.append(menu);

// add styling
const styleEl = document.createElement('style');
styleEl.innerHTML = `
  .dynMenu {
    position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 10px;
    z-index: 100; background-color: #ddd;
    font-family: 'Verdana'; padding: 0;
  }
  .dynMenu div {
    padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dynMenu div:hover {
     background-color: #eee;
   }
`;
document.querySelector('head').append(styleEl);


// add event listener
menu.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let optionEl = e.target.closest('div');
  if (!optionEl) { return; }
  let choice = optionEl.innerText;
  // Do stuff here depending on choice
  alert('You chose ' + choice);
});
```